# how to call a method in one component from another component is angular2

Tags: angular

Here method load() is defined in  `app.component.ts` and `<app-child></app-child>` is passed in   `app.component.html` and `'load('1', 'value', msc)'` method is called from   `child.component.html`.

How to call the method load()?

```
app.component.ts
    -----------------
    load(id, value, msc){
    alert(id)
    }
    app.component.html
    ----------------------
    <app-child></app-child>

    child.component.html
    ---------------------
    <div (click)= 'load('1', 'value', msc)'>btn1</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @Output and emit an object wraping your three parameters:

```js
// app.component.ts:
    
load(id, value, msc){
    alert(id)
}

loadEv = ($event) => {
    this.load($event.param1, $event.param2, $event.param3);
}

// app.component.html:

<app-child (loadEvent) = loadEv($event)></app-child>

// child.component.html:

<div (click)= 'load('1', 'value', msc)'>btn1</div>

// child.component.ts:

import { Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Output() loadEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();

load(param1, param2, param3): any {
  this.loadEvent.emit({param1, param2, param3});
}
```

Comment: <app-child (loadEvent) = loadEv($target)></app-child> . there is some error at  $target.

Comment: Sorry, typo: in the template, $event instead of $target

Comment: There is error in snippet too as not getting alert.

Comment: You cannot run the snippet, it's not a complete code

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared service and make a common function usable in both the components

Answer (score 0):

You can use event binding for this:

```
// parent template
<app-child (onLoad)="load(...$event)></app-child>

// child template
<div (click)='onLoad.emit(['1', 'value', msc])'>btn1</div>    

// child controller
@Output() onLoad = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#custom-events-with-eventemitter

Comment: Thanks, I will study it . Can you help in above question with easy method.